# Linphone - project android

Tags: build, linphone

I got error after executing command **make** .

> -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.10")  CMake Error at cmake/Tools.cmake:31 (message):   'pystache' python module
>   not found Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:177
>   (check_python_module)
>
> make[3]: ***
>   [linphone-android/WORK/android-arm64/Stamp/EP_linphone/EP_linphone-configure]
>   Error 1 make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/EP_linphone.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]:
>    **[all] Error 2 make: *** [arm64-build] Error 2

I use mac os ,

sh-3.2# python --version
Python 2.7.10

important : 
pip3 works but pip command not found!

**Update :**  I found solution with :

```
   brew uninstall python


   brew install python@2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was because you did not have the module: "pystache".
Make sure you have installed pip 
And then, you can:
pip install pystache

Reference:
https://pypi.org/project/pystache/